# Sum attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model that has a 'percentage' attribute

I would like to make sure the sum of of all 'percentage' is not > 100 when adding new values.

In my model, I have

```
validate :sum_can_not_exceed_hundred
def sum_can_not_exceed_hundred
  if Result.all.sum(:percentage) > 100
    errors.add(:base, :sum_can_not_exceed_hundred)
  end
end
```

But this does not work for adding the records that are not on the db and those are are already saved.

Update:
    The following seems to work, using a hint from Coderhs

```
if Result.where.not(id: self.id).sum(:percentage_share) + self.percentage_share > 100
    errors.add(:base, :sum_can_not_exceed_hundred)
end
```

Comment: you can call a method on ##before_create :check_percentage

Answer (score 2):

Since your table is new it won't be available on Result.all. Try modifying the code like so

```
validate :sum_can_not_exceed_hundred
  def sum_can_not_exceed_hundred
    sum = if self.id
       Result.all.sum(:percentage)
    else
      self.percentage + Result.all.sum(:percentage)
    end
    errors.add(:base, :sum_can_not_exceed_hundred) if sum > 100
  end
end
```

Comment: But this will not work on editing, since Result.all includes the row that is being edited, right?

Comment: Simplest fix would be add a condition to check if its happening on create or update.